# Any method could let code in scrollviewDidScroll be executed only once?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Due to `-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` will be called many times when scrolling, the inner code of this method also will be called many times.

But I want to the inner code only be called once and after conditions changed, the inner code could be called again.

My code:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
     NSLog(@"main %f", self.mainScrollView.contentOffset.y);
    if (self.mainScrollView.contentOffset.y<99 ) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"disableInteraction" object:nil];
        //If satisfied the if condition, only post Notification for once, after self.mainScrollView.contentOffset.y = 0, postNotification could be call again
    }
    else{

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"enableInteraction" object:nil];
    }
}
```

If satisfied the if condition, only post Notification for once, after self.mainScrollView.contentOffset.y = 0, postNotification could be call again

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
     if ((self.mainScrollView.contentOffset.y<99) && (!notified)) {
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"disableInteraction" object:nil];
         notified = true;
     } 
     else if (self.mainScrollView.contentOffset.y = 0){
          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"enableInteraction" object:nil];
          notified = false;
     }
}
```